# Selenium+Ruby issue because of page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've the following code:

```
wait.until {driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@class='btn btn-success Testserver']")}
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@class='btn btn-success Testserver']")
element.click
wait.until {driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@class='btn btn-success Testserver2']")}
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@class='btn btn-success Testserver2']")
element.click
```

My problem is the 3rd and the 4th line. When selenium clicks the first element, it causes a page reload. The problem is that the 4th line (the wait.until) finds the element BEFORE the reload is executed. So what happens? Selenium thinks the element is already loaded, it try to continue and after that the pages reload and selenium throw out an error, cause it can't find the element.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
```

What can i do? The code works fine when i put a sleep between this lines, but i don't wan't to use sleep cause of bad practice. Is there another way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe you need to also check if document is ready in the second `wait.until` block.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a well-known issue with Selenium. It's hard to wait for a new page to load if the old page and the new page both have the element you're testing for.

There are workarounds that include explicitly rescuing from  `StaleElementReferenceError` and using that as a condition to check for so you know when the page has finished reloading. See [How to get Selenium to wait for page load after a click](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html).

In ruby it would look something like this (not tested):

```
def wait_until_reload(&block)
  old_element = driver.find_element(:tag_name, 'html')
  yield
  wait.until do
    begin
      old_element.first(id: 'doesnt-matter')
      false
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError
      true
    end
  end
end

wait_until_reload { element.click }
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll read the article and try it. Think my ruby-knowledge should be good enough to get your code working, if he doesnt yet (didn't tested til now).
I'll post my sourcecode when i've solved my problem.